# ¿Cómo soluciono este problema con los DLL en Python 3.7.9 Shell?

Tags: python, python-3.7, dll

Me ocurren estos errores al correr mi programa y al intentar instalar en_core_web_sm con el siguiente comando:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Tanto en el Shell de Python como en el cmd manda todos estos errores.
Intenté reinstalando Python por completo pero no funcionó.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\Desktop\ChatBot.py", line 1, in 
> from chatterbot import ChatBot
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
> from .chatterbot import ChatBot
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 2, in 
> from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
> from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 3, in 
> from chatterbot.tagging import PosLemmaTagger
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 3, in 
> import spacy
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
> from .errors import setup_default_warnings
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\errors.py", line 2, in 
> from .compat import Literal
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\compat.py", line 38, in 
> from thinc.api import Optimizer  # noqa: F401
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py", line 2, in 
> from .initializers import normal_init, uniform_init, glorot_uniform_init, zero_init
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\initializers.py", line 4, in 
> from .backends import Ops
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\backends_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
> from .ops import Ops
> File "C:\Users\ghxst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\backends\ops.py", line 15, in 
> from .cblas import CBlas
> ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Comment: te recomiendo especificar una version para cada uno de esos paquetes. Segun la version de Python, algunos paquetes pueden estar disponibles en versiones especificas

Comment: Tenia que poner los DLL en la misma ubicación